# Spring JPA creates entity with null values

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following code:

```
groupModel.getUserFormGroups().clear();
for(MemberDTO member : group.getMembers()){
    User u = userRepository.findByEmail(member.getEmail());
    System.out.println(member.getEmail() + " " + groupModel.getName() + " " + member.getRole());
    if(u == null){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    groupModel.getUserFormGroups().add(new UserFormGroup(u, groupModel, UserFormGroupRole.ADMIN));
}

try{
    groupRepository.save(groupModel);
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    System.out.println(e.getClass());
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY).build();
}
```

When I run this, the new `UserFormGroups` have an id and all the other fields are null. Is there something wrong with fully updating a ManyToOne relationship?

On the group entity I have the following OneToMany relation:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=UserFormGroup.class, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "formGroup", orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<UserFormGroup> userFormGroups = new HashSet<>();
```

And the UserFormGroup relation looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user", "form_group"})
})
public class UserFormGroup implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user",referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "form_group", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private FormGroup formGroup;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private UserFormGroupRole role;

    public UserFormGroup() {
    }

    public UserFormGroup(User user, FormGroup group, UserFormGroupRole role) {
        this.user = user;
        this.formGroup = group;
        this.role = role;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public FormGroup getFormGroup() {
        return formGroup;
    }

    public void setFormGroup(FormGroup formGroup) {
        this.formGroup = formGroup;
    }

    public UserFormGroupRole getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(UserFormGroupRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Comment: is groupRepository a JpaRepository? And to be clear, the UserFormGroup entities are created but with just the id and foreign key to the GroupModel?

Comment: More like a spring data repository, it extends CrudRepository. They are created but only the id is set, role is null, form_group is null and user is null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not 100% but in my opinion, the problem might be following:

The `CrudRepository`'s implementation of the `save` method checks whether the object you are saving is a new or existing entity. If it is already an existing entity, it performs a `merge` operation. This would be the scenario that's happening in your case as the `groupModel` is an existing entity.

Now on the `@OneToMany` dependency, you only have these cascade options:

`cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }`

If you add `CascadeType.MERGE` the operation should be propagated to the UserFromGroup entities and persist them (the default behavior of merge when the entities are new ones).

Comment: This seems to work but I have the following error `Duplicate entry '1-8' for key` when I add a UserFormGroup that was already into the FormGroup. Probably because the orphan is deleted after the new one is created

Comment: Fixed it by retrieving the UserFormGroup if it already exists and creating it if it doesn't. Thank you